Is $d(x+y)$ valid and if so can you distribute the $d$?
I was trying to integrate the chemical rate equation:
$$\text{Rate} = k[A]^l[B]^m[C]^n...$$
by letting
$-\frac{d([A]+[B]+[C]+...)}{dt} = k[A]^l[B]^m[C]^n...$
and solving from there by distributing the $d$
$-kdt = \frac{d[A]+d[B]+d[C]+...)}{[A]^l[B]^m[C]^n...}$
etc.... (Including just in case I made a mistake because I am still a calculus beginner. Up to you if you want to check.)
$-kdt= \frac{d[A]}{[A]^l}\frac{1}{[B]^m[C]^n...}+\frac{d[B]}{[B]^m}\frac{1}{[A]^l[C]^n[D]^o...}+\frac{d[C]}{[C]^n}\frac{1}{[A]^l[B]^m[D]^o...}+...$
$-kt+C=\frac{[A]^{l+1}}{l+1}\frac{1}{[B]^m[C]^n...}+\frac{[B]^{m+1}}{m+1}\frac{1}{[A]^l[C]^n[D]^o...}+\frac{[C]^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{1}{[A]^l[B]^m[D]^o...}+...$
So I'm wondering is this correct because I have never seen it before. Is $d(x+y)$ possible and can we distribute?

Sure. This boils down to the standard fact in calculus that the derivative of the sum of functions is the sum of the derivatives.

Differentials are linear - so, yes.

Also note that your integrals are wrong. You integrate $[A]^l$, when you should integrate $[A]^{-l}$. And so on

You can make such a distribution thanks to the linearity of the derivative indeed, however you cannot integrate the right-hand side as you did, because the concentrations of each species are not independent variables a priori.
